# How to delete a cookie on server with JAX-RS NewCookie?

Tags: java, http, cookies, jax-rs

I want to delete cookie on server (by means of setting `Expires` to the past). How can I do this with `javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie`? I'm trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
return Response.ok()
  .entity("hello world!")
  .cookie(
    new NewCookie(
      "foo",
      "",
      "/",
      ".example.com",
      1,
      "no comment",
      0, // maxAge
      false
    )
  )
  .build();
```

This snippet produces this HTTP header:

```
Set-Cookie:foo=;Version=1;Comment="no comment";Domain=.example.com;Path=/
```

This header doesn't delete the cookie from the server. What is a possible workaround?

Comment: not a duplicate as this question specifically asks how to do it using JAX-RS `NewCookie` while the other question asks for a general HTTP approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how it works (rather dirty approach):

```
return Response.ok()
  .header(
    "Set-Cookie",
    "foo=deleted;Domain=.example.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT"
  );
```

Comment: Sorry, this response did not removed or changed cookie:
Response.ok()
  .header(
    "Set-Cookie",
    "foo=deleted;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT"
  );

Comment: For cookie: 
 name = "foo"
 value = "..."
 comment = null
 domain = null
 maxAge = -1
 path = null
 secure = false
 version = 0
 isHttpOnly = false

Answer (score 3):

I cannot try proposed, but it should work (since it is common work around for java servlet API to remove cookie).

Step 1. Get access to HttpServletResponse. To do it declare in your service something like:

```
@Context
HttpServletResponse _currentResponse;
```

Step 2. Let the client side chance to remove cookie by set expiration time

```
Cookie userCookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
_currentResponse.setContentType("text/html");
userCookie.setMaxAge(0);
_currentResponse.addCookie(userCookie);
```

Comment: This won't work b/c a cookie is deleted only when its Expires field is set to a date in the past

Comment: @Oleg - so you propose to add line to assign cookie date?

Comment: sorry please disregard, I didn't know that setMaxAge(0) would actually produce `Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT
`

Comment: @OlegMikheev Does it really do that? I can't find where this conversion happens in Jersey.

Comment: @GuiSim I've personally seen different kinds of behaviour of cookie.setMaxAge, I guess the answer is implementation specific

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!  Note that I'm setting the max age to 0 and the expiration date to the current time.

```
NewCookie mycookie= new NewCookie("mycookie", null, "/", "", NewCookie.DEFAULT_VERSION, null, 0, new Date(), false, false);
return Response.ok().cookie(mycookie).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

this works as well:

```
NewCookie mycookie = new NewCookie("mycookie", null, "/", null, null, 0, false, true);
return Response.ok().cookie(mycookie).build();
```

extract from response header:

```
set-cookie: mycookie=;Version=1;Path=/;Max-Age=0;HttpOnly
```